# UWP Toolkit DataGrid Cells Padding/Margin

Tags: windows, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm struggling to remove/clear the padding/margin of `DataGrid` cells.

[image]

Appreciate if anyone can help how to remove the padding/margin. I'm using `DataGridTextColumn` because I need the `TextBox` for editing the value. I have manage to remove the padding/margin for the `TextBox` by setting the style for `EditingElementStyle`, that is;

```xml
    <Style x:Key="tbEntry" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="45" />
    </Style>
```

However, I cannot change the styles padding/margin for the cells after the `TextBox` unfocus. I have try setting on `CellStyle` or `ElementStye` of `DataGridTextColumn` with no luck.

Comment: Hello, can you provide XAML code for reference? In the case of the automatically generated `DataGrid.Column`, double-click the cell to enter the editing state, and the `Padding` property value is 0. The cell's default `Padding` property value is also 0. So you may need to provide XAML code so that we can analyze possible problems. Since the TextBox has a default minimum height, you can try to extend it to the entire cell by adding `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`

Comment: Not the TextBox part that I'm asking. But the Cell part. Repro: Set the width of the cell column to 45 as an example, then enter number 123 inside the cell. You can see the number inside the cell cropped. I believe this is because Padding of the cell content.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT I have tested using HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" and apply on both ElementStyle and also CellStyle of the DataGridTextColumn. Both did not work as well.

Comment: Hello, I am sorry that the previous comment did not help you. I looked at the source code of the `DataGrid` and found the default style of the `DataGridCell`. Unfortunately, the default Padding property of Cell is 0, but the content of Cell is displayed by `ContentPresenter`. It also has no Padding property, so I can confirm that there is a control between Cell and display text, but we can't directly control the Padding value of it, so for now, you can't modify this part. I suggest you use `ListView` to build a *DataGrid like* to achieve a custom effect that better suits your requirements.

Comment: Okay, I will add this as issue on the GitHub for Windows Toolkit source code. Thanks for highlighting the issue.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT btw, I don't think ListView a best option, because the table has 50~100 dynamic columns. I appreciated if you have an example using ListView for this scenario.

Comment: ListView has virtualization, and performance optimization is performed when loading large amounts of data to ensure loading efficiency, so you don't have to worry too much about performance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Riza, you can control the margin used in non-editing mode by using a custom text column instead of the DataGridTextColumn. Use this one:

```
public class MyDataGridTextColumn : DataGridTextColumn
{
    public MyDataGridTextColumn()
    {
    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        TextBlock textBlock = base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem) as TextBlock;
        textBlock.Margin = new Thickness(2, 0, 2, 0);
        return textBlock;
    }
}
```

...and adjust the margin as you wish. Thanks.

Comment: I consider this as an alternative answer from Style. I tested and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What about this example?

```
xmlns:toolkit="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
```

...

```
<toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Lng" Tag="Lng">
 <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Lng, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="1,1,1,1" Padding="1,1,1,1">
   </TextBlock>
  </DataTemplate>
 </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```